# Why does presence of value evaluate as "Truthy" in Python? [e.i. Types evaluate True in conditionals]

Tags: python, conditions

Example:

```
if float: print('float is true?')
```

returns:

[image]

Why do all objects other than ones explicitly defined as False or "False" evaluate truthfully?

Comment: What do you mean *"reason"*? See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python language is strongly influenced by C. And C is a horrible language that didn't even have a boolean type until C99. Instead, it has integers. Anything that looks like a zero integer is false, anything else is true. It turns out that this is mightily convenient.

Wanna test for a null pointer? Unlike Java, you don't have to spell out `if (thing != null) foo(thing);` – a `if (thing) foo(thing);` suffices.
Wanna check if we reached the end of a string? Just dereference it in a conditional:

```
char c;
while ((c = *str++)) do_something(c);
```

Wanna check if an array contains any items? Just test for the length:

```
int n;
...;
if (n) we_have_items();
```

So conceptually, a conditional has two forms:

- a predicate form with some expression that evaluates to a boolean-interpretable value.
- a container form with a single variable to check that this container is not-empty.

While Python has actual boolean types rather than overloading integers, it keeps this very popular mechanism for collections. For example, `None` (Python's `null` equivalent), empty strings `""`, empty lists `[]`, and empty dicts `{}` all evaluate to `False` in a boolean context. This usually does what you want, and if it doesn't, you can be explicit about your requirements. For example, you can specifically test that a variable is not `None`:

```
if x is not None:
  do_something_with(x)
```

However, if you know that `name` is an optional string, then writing

```
if name:
  print("hello, ", name)
else:
  print("name required!")
```

is much more comfortable than

```
if bool(name):  # manually force to-bool conversion
  ...
```

or

```
if name is not None and len(name):  # explicitly state your intent: at least one character
  ...
```

or

```
if name is not None and bool(len(name)): # what the above example really means
   ...
```

or

```
if name is not None and len(xs) > 0:  # even more explicit
  ...
```

It is important to note that these implicit conversions are not black magic that pull the comfy rug of type safety away from under your feet. In Python, these conversions always happen quite explicitly, but if you pass a function or a builtin some value, it may perform any such conversions on that argument. For example, you can explicitly request a bool conversion via `bool(some_value)`. So if you want to, you can think of the `if EXPRESSION: ...` builtin as being implemented like:

```
def if(EXPRESSION, then, else):
  real_if bool(EXPRESSION):
    then()
  real_else:
    else()
```

You can also define your own to-bool conversion for your own classes, by implementing the special `__bool__(self)` method. But careful! Conversions and operator overloading can get quite confusing for a user unless the semantics are obvious and intuitive. In Python, it is considered sufficiently clear for a to-bool conversion to test whether a collection or container is empty. For non-containers, it might be a good idea to use an ordinary, named method instead.

So why does it make sense for values to evaluate to `True` even when no to-bool conversion has been defined? User-defined types generally have reference semantics, i.e. the variable holds a pointer to the value, not the value itself. As we have seen, the `if (pointer) ...` C idiom tests whether a pointer is not empty, so it makes some sense to extend it even to Python which does not have reified pointers. So the conditional here does not test whether the value is true or false, but whether the variable currently holds a value. If the type had value semantics, I would find such a to-bool conversion highly confusing, but that might just be the C++-programmer in me speaking.

Answer (score -1):

> Why do all objects other than ones explicitly defined as False or "False" evaluate truthfully?

## Simple explanation:

Because they do, *by definition*.  Sorry if that seems like a tautology, but that really is the correct answer: this is the arbitrary way it works because that is the arbitrary way it is specified to work in the arbitrary, *canonical* rules of the language.

## Philosophical explanation:

Have a look at [the Zen of Python,](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) which states:

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

If the rules are that "this specific set of values are falsy and everything else is truthy," then even though it seems nonsensical to have a reference to a type being either truthy or falsy, that's a special case, and it's not special enough to break the rules.

## Flame bait explanation:

Because Python lacks a proper static type system, in which the only `True` and `False` values would be `True` and `False`, and anything else would be rejected at compile time.  And since you can't do that in a dynamic language, Python takes the easy way out instead of spending extra effort to do it "the right way" (and good luck defining that in this context!) even when it means accepting obviously-invalid and nonsensical code.

## Take your pick ;-)

Comment: So it is advantageous when writing a language to define rules and only worry about certain known cases of instances where those rules are broken and cause problems? Rather than to only allow certain known instances to work?

Comment: @RubenBaden: That's one advantageous way of doing it.  It kind of depends on your philosophy.  It's important to be *consistent,* though, [so your users know what to expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), or you can end up with a [huge, ugly mess of inconsistency that breaks in horrible ways if you so much as look at it funny.](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)  That's one of the things that Python gets right: it's good at consistently adhering to the basic design principles laid out in the Zen of Python.

Comment: Huh? What does static typing have to do with implicit conversions? Many very static languages have them as well, e.g. C++ or Scala. Or do you also dislike operator overloading because it's so unobtrusive? In Python, you still have the option to distinguish whether something is just true-ish or actually true itself: `if x: ...` vs. `if x is True: ...`. Compared with Perl, Bash, or PHP, the Python language actually has a usable and clean type system – if you only knew it. -1.

Comment: "Because Python lacks a proper static type system, in which the only True and False values would be True and False, and anything else would be rejected at compile time.": I do not think the reason is dynamic typing. One could throw an exception each time a boolean is expected and something else is provided, in the same way as adding a number and a string throws.

Comment: @Giorgio I agree, that option _could_ have been chosen. As far as I can see, the reason it wasn't was: since there's no compiler to check types, and any object may be used in a conditional, we might as well try to be _useful_ rather than _safe_ and use a reasonable strategy for non-Booleans (empty collections are falsy; most other objects are truthy). The useful/safe dichotomy is one of the fundamental tradeoffs in language design, and is why no one uses Cobol any more (too unsafe) and why no one uses Agda yet (not useful enough).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson: I did not want to argue about the usefulness of Python's solution. My point was that this solution is not enforced by the dynamic type system. For many data types that are monoids (boolean with `or`, integers with `+`, strings with `+`), it seems intuitive to choose the identity element (False, 0, '') as `false` and all other elements as `true`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson what do you mean that python doesn't have a compiler to enforce type checks?  It's an interpreted language, but you can get into type checking and errors from the interpreter.  For example: `'a' + 1` throws an exception `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Comment: @EricRenouf What it means is that if your Python program is complex enough that it can run for an hour before it hits the line of code in question, you won't know anything's wrong until you've been running it for an hour and then suddenly it throws a `TypeError` in your face.  If it had a compiler checking for things like that, you'd know before the program ever even starts up, minimizing aggravation and the chance of lost work.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Sure, it might be good to catch such errors earlier rather than later, but that's different from not having type checking which it seemed to me was what Ben was saying--but perhaps that's my bad reading I suppose